# Angularjs Select values are getting removed from ngModel after being added programmicatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-select, ui-select2

I am using Angularjs with select2. I have a multiselect box that gets populated based off the values selected in another dropdown. I use an click event on a button for fire a method that adds a list of ids to the ngModel object assigned to the multiselect box. I can see the values getting added properly after I trigger a change event on that form element because even after reading articles and changing the ngModel value to be a object and not an array, the values still aren't binding when I add them programmatically. After I trigger the change event on the form element, I am able to see some of the values but not all of them. Some of the values were removed. Below is my code.

addRecord.vm

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <select ui-select2="{ allowClear: false, minimumResultsForSearch: 10, theme: bootstrap }"
        name="recordTemplate" ng-model="addRecordCtrl.selectedTemplate">
        <option class="selectPlaceholder" value="" disabled selected hidden>- Chose Record Template -</option>
        <option ng-repeat="template in addRecordCtrl.recordTemplates" value="{{record.name}}">{{record.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <button id="addButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="addRecordCtrl.addRecords()" ng-disabled="addRecordCtrl.isLoading 
|| addRecordCtrl.isEdit">Add</button>
 </div>

<div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-9" id="recordContainer" name="recordContainer">
     <select ui-select2="{ allowClear: false, minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity}"
         name="records" id="records" class="medium"
         multiple ng-model="addRecordCtrl.records.id"
         ng-required="true" ng-cloak>
             <option ng-repeat="record in addRecordCtrl.availableRecords | notInArray:addRecordCtrl.selectedRecordIds.ids:'recordId'"
                value="{{record.recordId}}">{{record.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="addRecordCtrl.selectedRecordName" value="">
</div>
```

app.js

```
recordApp.controller('RecordController', ['$http', '$window', '$modal', '$log','$filter', '$timeout', function ($http, $window, $modal, $log, $filter, $timeout) {

    var self = this;
    self.availableRecords = [{
        recordId: "1",
        name: "Love and Happiness"
    },{
        recordId: "2",
        name: "Feel the Burn"
    },{
        recordId: "3",
        name: "Juicy Baby"
    }];
    self.recordTemplates = null;
    self.selectedRecordIds = {};

    self.addRecords = function () {

        //add record ids from the selected records.
        self.recordTemplates.recordId.forEach(function (id) {
            self.selectedRecordIds.ids.push(id.recordId);
        });

        self.recordAdded = true;
    };

}]);
//filter to filter out ids that have already been selected.
recordsApp.filter('notInArray', ['$filter', function($filter){
    return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
        if(arrayFilter){
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayFilter.length; i++) {
                    if (arrayFilter[i][element] == listItem[element])
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I stopped at "Angularjs 1.2.23". If you care about avoiding bugs, you shouldn't use such an obsolete version. We're at version 1.6.9. Dozens of versions have been released since 1.2.23.

Comment: Thank you for your insight @JBNizet but when you work for a big corporation that you just joined less then a year ago, you don't get the option to just go around upgrading stuff. If only we existed in a world in ideal world where we always had that option available to us. But again, thank you very much for insightful words.

Comment: Any chance you could repro in a fiddle or plunkr?

Comment: @tymeJV I have never done that before but i can try and post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason some of my values were getting deleted from the selectedRecordIds array after adding them programmatically was because they are not in the availableRecords array. Once I made sure those values where in the availableRecords array all was well.